# how to show this statement?(Topology[closed and compact])

Tags: general-topology

$Q)$ Let the $T_u$ be a usual topology and $T=\{G \subset \mathbb R^2 \vert \ \mathbb R^2 - G\ $is a compact on $(\mathbb R^2, T_u)\}$ (co-compact topology) on $\mathbb R^2$

For $A( \neq \phi) \subset \mathbb R^2$, Show the below.

$A$ is a compact on  $(\mathbb R^2, T)$ $\iff A$ is the closed set on $(\mathbb R^2, T_u)$

In solution sheet, it doesn't have any solution or idea for that. Though, I tried to solve it by myself over and over, the result is always failed.

Please help me to prove that.

Comment: What is "a usual topology"? The norm topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: And also, what have you tried? Please give some indication of your own attempts.

Comment: How is $\emptyset$ open in $T$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ and $\mathscr{U}\subseteq T\setminus\{\varnothing\}$ be an open cover of $A$. For each $U\in\mathscr{U}$ let $K_U=\Bbb R^2\setminus U$; $K_U$ is compact in the Euclidean topology on $\Bbb R^2$. By DeMorgan’s laws we have

$$\bigcup\mathscr{U}=\bigcup_{U\in\mathscr{U}}\left(\Bbb R^2\setminus K_U\right)=\Bbb R^2\setminus\bigcap_{U\in\mathscr{U}}K_U\,,$$

so $A\cap\bigcap_{U\in\mathscr{U}}K_U=\varnothing$.

If $A$ is closed in the Euclidean topology, let $C_U=A\cap K_U$ for each $U\in\mathscr{U}$; then each $C_U$ is compact in the Euclidean topology, and $$\bigcap_{U\in\mathscr{U}}C_U=\varnothing\,.\tag{1}$$ Suppose that no finite subset of $\mathscr{U}$ covers $A$. Then for each finite $\mathscr{F}\subseteq\mathscr{U}$ we have

$$A\nsubseteq\bigcup\mathscr{F}=\Bbb R^2\setminus\bigcap_{U\in\mathscr{F}}K_U\,,$$

so $A\cap\bigcap_{U\in\mathscr{F}}K_U\ne\varnothing$, and hence

$$\bigcap_{U\in\mathscr{F}}C_U=\bigcap_{U\in\mathscr{F}}(A\cap K_U)=A\cap\bigcap_{U\in\mathscr{F}}K_U\ne\varnothing\,.$$

Now fix $U_0\in\mathscr{U}$. Then for each finite $\mathscr{F}\subseteq\mathscr{U}$ we have

$$\bigcap_{U\in\mathscr{F}}(C_{U_0}\cap C_U)=\bigcap_{U\in\mathscr{F}\cup\{U_0}C_U\ne\varnothing\,,$$

so $\{C_{U_0}\cap C_U:U\in\mathscr{U}\}$ has the [finite intersection property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_intersection_property). $C_{U_0}$ is compact in the Euclidean topology, and in that topology each of the sets $C_{U_0}\cap C_U$ is a closed subset of $C_{U_0}$, so by a [standard result](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/11/30/the-finite-intersection-property-in-compact-spaces-and-countably-compact-spaces/)

$$\bigcap_{U\in\mathscr{U}}C_U=\bigcap_{U\in\mathscr{U}}(C_{U_0}\cap C_U)\ne\varnothing\,,$$

contradicting $(1)$. It follows that there must be some finite $\mathscr{F}\subseteq\mathscr{U}$ such that

$$A\cap\bigcap_{U\in\mathscr{F}}K_U=\bigcap_{U\in\mathscr{U}}C_U=\varnothing$$

and hence

$$A\subseteq\Bbb R^2\setminus\bigcap_{U\in\mathscr{F}}K_U=\bigcup\mathscr{F}\,,$$

i.e., $\mathscr{F}$ is a finite subfamily of $\mathscr{U}$ that covers $A$. $\mathscr{U}$ was an arbitrary open cover of $A$ in the co-compact topology, so $A$ is compact in the co-compact topology.

Now suppose that $A$ is not closed in the Euclidean topology. Then there is a point $p\in(\operatorname{cl}_{T_u}A)\setminus A$. For each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let

$$K_n=\left\{x\in\Bbb R^2:d(x,p)\le\frac1n\right\}\,,$$

where $d$ is the usual Euclidean metric, and let $x_n\in A\cap B_d\left(p,\frac1n\right)\subseteq K_n$. Let $U_n=\Bbb R^2\setminus K_n$, and let $\mathscr{U}=\{U_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$. Each of the sets $K_n$ is compact in the Euclidean topology, and

$$A\cap\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}K_n=A\cap\{p\}=\varnothing\,,$$

so $A\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr{U}$, i.e., $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $A$. It’s easy to see, however, that no finite subset of $\mathscr{U}$ covers $A$. Clearly $U_m\subseteq U_n$ whenever $1\le m\le n$, so if $\mathscr{F}\subseteq\mathscr{U}$ is finite, and $$m=\max\{n\in\Bbb Z^+:U_n\in\mathscr{F}\}\,,$$ then

$$\bigcup\mathscr{F}=U_m=\Bbb R^2\setminus K_n\subseteq\Bbb R^2\setminus\{x_n\}\,,$$

so $x_n\in A\setminus\bigcup\mathscr{F}$, and $\mathscr{F}$ does not cover $A$. That is, no finite subset of $\mathscr{U}$ covers $A$, so $A$ is not compact in the co-compact topology.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for your described collection of sets to be a topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ it needs to include the empty set $\emptyset$. With $\emptyset$ adjoined, it is a topology and we will denote it by $T$.

I will first show that if $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the euclidean topology, that it is compact with respect to $T$.

Consider the topology $ T_c= \{G \cup \{\infty \} : G \in T \} \cup T_{\mathbb{R}^2}$ on the one point compactification $\mathbb{R}^2 \cup \{\infty \}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, where $T_{\mathbb{R}^2}$ is the euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be closed. Then $A \cup \{\infty\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \cup \{\infty \}$ is compact with respect to $T_c$. Indeed, since $(\mathbb{R}^2 \cup \{\infty \}, T_c)$ is a compact space, it is enough to show that $A \cup \{\infty \}$ is closed , which follows easily since $\mathbb{R}^2 \cup \{\infty\} \setminus (A \cup \{\infty\}) = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the euclidean topology, and hence it is in $T_c$. Finally, suppose $\{G_{\alpha} \}$ is a collection of sets of $T$ covering $A$, which holds if and only if $\{G_{\alpha} \cup \{\infty \} \}$ (which is a collection of open sets of $T_c$) covers $A \cup \{\infty \}$, and since $A$ adjoined with $\infty$ is compact, this has a finite subcover, then removing $\{\infty \}$ from each of the open sets in this finite subcover gives a finite subcover of sets of our original collection of sets of $T$ that covers $A$. So this shows that $A$ is compact with respect to $T$.

We now show the other side:

Let $y$ be a point of closure of $A$ (as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the euclidean topology). We show that if $y \notin A$, that $A$ is not compact with respect to $T$.

Assume for the sake of a contradiction that $y \notin A$.

Fix any $r > 0$, then $cl(B_{r}(y))$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the euclidean topology. There is some $0<r'<r$ such that for every $z \in \partial(B_{r}(y))$ such that $z \in A$, $z \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus cl(B_{r'}(y))$. Now put $U_1 = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus cl(B_r(y))$ and $U_2 = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus cl(B_{r'}(y))$.

Now for every $w \in B_r(y) \cap A$ there is some $0 < \Delta_w < r$ such that $w \notin cl(B_{\Delta_w}(y))$ (since $y \notin A $), so in other words we have that there is such a $\Delta_w$ so that $w \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus cl(B_{\Delta_w}(y)) = V_w$.

Finally we have that $\{U_1,U_2 \} \cup \{V_w : w \in B_{r}(y) \cap A \}$ is a open cover of $A$.

Suppose this has some finite subcover consisting of $\{V_{w_i}\}_{i=1}^k$ only out of all the possible $V_w$ sets, and let $\Delta = \min(\min(\{\Delta_{w_i}\}_{i=1}^k),r')$. Now consider $B_{\Delta}(y)$. Then if $w \in B_{\Delta}(y) \cap A$ then $w$ is not in $U_1$ or $U_2$ or any $V_{w_i}$ for $i=1,...,k$. Since $B_{\Delta}(y) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ (since $y$ is a point of closure of $A$) this gives us a contradiction.

Hence we have shown the contrapositive of the other side, i.e. that if $A$ is not closed with respect to the euclidean topology then it is not compact with respect to $T$.